# AWS -SES verifying business email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

How do i verify my custom business email id through amazon ses. i tried the usual way of how to verify gmail but it does not work. I am not receiving any verification email. I have also verified my domain name in AWS SES.
Should i follow someother method?

Comment: Hope this will help you out :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html

Comment: @sumanthshetty. I followed the same steps. I have not received a verification email. If i send it to my personal email id it comes. But not to the business email id.

Comment: Please check your spam or other folder. This happens when there are segregation filters set on your email